# Is the increased proper time of earth due to its orbital motion around the sun equal the increased proper time due to GR?

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity

The proper time $d\tau$ and coordinate time $dt$ are connected by
 $$\gamma d \tau=dt$$

where

$$\gamma=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\frac {{v}^2} {{c}^2}}}$$

This is, for example, the reasons that muons can travel much farther through our atmosphere than expected because their proper time increases.

Now if we fill in for $v$ in $\gamma$ the velocity of the earth around the sun, will this give the same result as predicted by the general theory of relativity, which is to say, will the increased time be the same as GR predicts for points at the same distance as the earth is orbiting the sun (assuming the earth orbit is circular?

Comment: No. They are different. One is due to relative motion, and you get it from special relativity. The other one is due to gravity, and depends on the gravitational potential. At some  distance from the central body they cancel each other. One increases the other decreases as you go further away. There's other answers on this for earth satellites, same equation with different numbers for your case.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [What is the correct formula for gravitational time dilation for a satellite in a circular orbit?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/154617/what-is-the-correct-formula-for-gravitational-time-dilation-for-a-satellite-in-a)

Comment: See also: [Is gravitational time dilation different from other forms of time dilation?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/110669/is-gravitational-time-dilation-different-from-other-forms-of-time-dilation/110675#110675)

Comment: and: [Does Earth experience any significant, measurable time dilation at perihelion?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/321910/does-earth-experience-any-significant-measurable-time-dilation-at-perihelion)

Comment: @JohnRennie-I was fiddling around with the Schwarzschild metric, but when I saw your reference to the second question  (and actually read it) I saw how the calculation was done! Great!+1!